# I have 2 lists(name of months and expenses). I have to input expense from the user and tell the month name which had the same expense

Tags: python

```
month_list = ["January","Februarty","March","April","May"]
expense_list = [2340, 2500, 2100, 3100, 2980]
exp = int(input("Enter your expense:"))
for i in range(5):
    if exp == expense_list[i]:
        print('Your expense matches with the month of',month_list[i])
    else:
        print('Your expense does not matches with the list')
        break
```

I tried this code but it's running only if I enter the expense of 1st month, for rest of the months it's not working.
**Please help**

Comment: Can you please format the code

Answer (score 3):

You want to break from the loop if it matches. That way the `else` will execute if there is no match. Use:

```
month_list = ["January","Februarty","March","April","May"]
expense_list = [2340, 2500, 2100, 3100, 2980]
exp=int(input("Enter your expense:"))
for i in range(5):
 if exp==expense_list[i]:
  print('Your expense matches with the month of',month_list[i])
  break
else:
  print('Your expense does not matches with the list')
```

A better way:

```
for x, y in zip(month_list, expense_list):
    if y == exp:
        print('Your expense matches with the month of ', x)
        break
else:
    print('Your expense does not matches with the list')
```

Comment: This answer is much more effective then mine!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make an array.

**For example:**

```
month_list = [
    ["January", '2340'],
    ["Februarty", '2500'],
    ["March", '2100'],
    ["April", '3100'],
    ["May", '2980']
]

exp = int(input("Enter your expense:"))

for x in range(len(month_list)):
    if exp == int(month_list[x][1]):
        matched_month = month_list[x][0]
        is_matched = True 

try:
    if is_matched == True: #When matched, is_matched will be set to True, but if not matched it wil throw up an error, which means that it is not matched
        print('Your expense matches with the month of',matched_month) 
except:
    print('Your expense does not matches with the list')
```

It's a long piece of code, but I hope it helps!